# jquery get a ul that is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to get a ul to show when a page initially loads, but I am having trouble doing that. Considering when I inspect the html, its not there, but a link that I click will expose it on the refresh.

Here's what I see before:

```
<div class=" socialpost twitter reply inbound">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="deletedByContainer">
<div class="deletedBy">
</div></div>
<div class="deleteFail"></div>
 --> Hidden ul and li are here <--
</div>
```

Here's what I see after the link is clicked:

```
<div class=" socialpost twitter reply inbound">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="deletedByContainer">
<div class="deletedBy">
</div></div>
<div class="deleteFail"></div>
<ul class="intents">
   <li class="intent reply"></li>
   <li class="intent favorite"></li>
   <li class="intent like"></li>
   <li class="intent retweet"></li>
   <li class="intent follow">
  <ul class="loading" ... etc.
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery and I am trying to sort it out, but am struggling:

```
j$(function(){
        j$("ul.intents:hidden").show();
 });
```

EDIT: 
ALSO TRIED

```
j$(function(){
        j$("ul.intents").show();
        });
```

and

```
j$("ul.intents").show();
```

I know jQuery is working because my other code is, but I am not sure how to get this to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not : ``j$("ul.intents").show();``

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial try, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML for the `<ul>` elements is unavailable at pageload (i.e. when your jQuery executes), then the elements are not hidden — they're missing entirely. In this case, the problem is further up the chain (i.e. whatever is generating the page HTML). You will want to make sure that the `<ul>` elements exist in the HTML before you can `.show()` them.

Otherwise, `jQuery.fn.show()` will only show elements that are `display:none`. Somewhat counterintuitively, elements that have `visibility: hidden` or `opacity:0` are not considered `:hidden` by jQuery. [See the jQuery API reference on `:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Comment: So what you're saying is they don't exist (not hidden) at initial page load, but only when I have 'refreshed' the page do they actually appear?

Comment: Sure. It appears that you're saying the `<ul>` is hidden from the source, which means it doesn't exist at all. Hidden from the source ≠ hidden from the user/view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code after appending the content. You have added the code in DOM ready where the element does not exists. also you can simply use:

```
j$("ul.intents").show();
```

Comment: you have to ensure that you write the code after appending intents.

Comment: I'm not appending intents, just trying to get it from the DOM...I didn't write the html. Just trying to expose it.

Comment: and how are they getting added on page

Comment: it gets loaded from an external system that I don't have the code to.